# ArrayList object sorting confusion

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I understand it is kind of repeated question.

But , I m stuck at this.

```
public class Ooops<P, O> 
{
   private P po;
   private O pa;
   private int val;
   public Preference(P p, O o, int v) 
   {
        setPo(p);
        setPa(o);
        setValue(v);
   }
   //Getter and setter for Pa,Pa and val
}
```

I have created an Object of this class

```
   List<Ooops<String, String>> abc = new ArrayList<Oops<String, String>>();
```

Something like ,

```
 Acf,PQR,8
 ABC,Pas,6
 AdC,PhR,3
```

Becomes

```
 AdC,PhR,3
 ABC,Pas,6
 Acf,PQR,8
```

I am confused , how can I sort the object based on the value of val in the object.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Ooops<P, O> implements Comparable<Ooops<P, O>> {

    // your code

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Ooops<P, O> other) {
       return other.val - this.val;
    }

}
```

---

Later on you can simply call

```
Collections.sort(yourList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Ooops class needs to implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).  Alternatively, you need to pass a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to the sort method.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `Comparable` from your Ooops and override the compareTo() .In the `compareTo()` you can have your own logic there to define the sorting order.As an examples

```
 @Override
    public int compareTo(Ooops<P, O> other) {
       return (this.po.getPoCount()+this.pa.getPaCount()) - (other.po.getPoCount()+other.pa.getPaCount());
    }
```

note that `getPoCount()` and `getPaCount()` are just some dummy methods.

You can get the `descending order` by just `multiplying` the above return value by `-1`.

**Using Comparator will also sort the list for you**